# How to determine which version of Android Studio I'm using?

Tags: android-studio

Running into some problems today with the new Android Studio update.

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio020released

In this blog post, it says

To install 0.2, you'll need to install a new Studio bundle. In other words, we are not offering a patch update from 0.1.9 to 0.2.

If I go (on OSX) Android Studio -> About Android Studio, I see the following.  I've look around, and can't seem to determine any other version numbers.  Where do I find this?

[image]

Comment: There's now a patch from 0.1.9 to 0.2.0 so you can just run "check update" and it'll find and apply it.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't exactly what I was looking for.  What I'm interested in is when I'm running Android Studio, where do I find the current version number, i.e. 0.1.9 or 0.2.0?  The screenshot I posted from the about menu says AI-130.737825, but nothing about a version number.

Comment: i know, I was mostly commenting on the update thing. The only way I know to get the version number is to close the windows of all the project. Then the welcome panel shows up and the version is shown at the bottom. I'll file a bug.

Comment: Cool thanks.  Maybe you have insight on my real question though, posted here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625345/no-android-facet-found-issues-compiling-with-android-studio-0-2 No being able to determine the version number left me confused whether I really need to download and reinstall, or if I was already updated (which the auto-update would leave me to believe).

Answer (score 44):

If in **About Android Studio** you only see the build number, go to **Preferences**. From the menu: *File > Settings  ... (Settings dialog appears) ... Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Updates*. Here, both the current version and the build number are shown.

In this example, the current version is v1.2:

[image: Settings - Android Studio Version]

Answer (score 16):

**For Windows Users**
`Help > About`

**For Mac Users**
Click on `Android Studio > About Android Studio`

---

EXTRA INFORMATION! (Optional Read)

**Update:**
Now it shows the version of Android like this:

`Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch`
**which roughly evaluates to**

`{"Android Studio $version_name | $year.number.number" Patch}`

Comment: In 2022, on macOS, the about dialog only gives a build number.

Answer (score 9):

If you have mac you can just click on AndroidStudio -> About Android Studio to see the version number

[image]

The first line shows the version number

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If using Windows,  while in Android Studio, go to:

File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Updates

And look at "Current Version", where it will tell you which Android Studio version you are using.

Works for Android Studio 2.3

Comment: Appearance & Behavior >  System Settings > Updates

Answer (score 4):

To Check Your Current Version Of androidstudio.

Go To->build.grade(Module);
here dependencies & calss path here it shows your current your build tool and gradle version exactly this is your currently using android version.

here you can see your android studio version.

```
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:**4.1.1"**
```

*4.1.1 is currently using android version.*

Comment: Only this answer helped and I found my version in December 2022 as 7.0.1. 
In Help --> About , it is just mentioned as Android Studio Dolphin, no version number

Answer (score 3):

While entering into the android studio project,On top of the Window you can see the version number.

For an **Example** it should be like :

> ListViewMaster: [C:\users\ListViewMaster]: - Android Studio 1.0.1

Answer (score 2):

The build number indicates what version you have installed.

0.2.0 is 130.737825; 0.1.9 was 130.729444+

http://tools.android.com/recent

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: I don't understand how one would figure that out.  If I go to either of the two links you provided and search the page for "130.737825", I produces 0 hits, so I don't quite see how one would correlate 0.2.0 to 130.737825.

Comment: Take a look at the names of the packages available for download. (Expand 'Download for Other Platforms' for easy viewing.)

Answer (score 2):

On unix systems, this should work in a shell:

```sh
android-studio -version
```

Verified as functional on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Useful to android studio version without launching it.

Comment: `./studio.sh -version` on `bin` directory - in the case of archieve distribution.