# No Android facet found, issues compiling with Android Studio 0.2

Tags: android-studio, facet

So, following the advice on this SO post (sorry, I would comment there expect I don't have enough reputation)

[Gradle: FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614477/gradle-failure-could-not-determine-which-tasks-to-execute/17614814#17614814)

I removed the  tags from my .iml files, which allows me to compile.  But when I go to run the .apk on a device, I get the error

"Error running TestProject: No Android facet found for TestProject"

Can someone help please, just want to get back to writing Android apps!

Comment: In my project directory, I had two .iml files -AppNameProject/AppNameProject.iml and AppNameProject/AppName/AppName.iml

The project-level one is where you need to delete the component tag, but you need the Android Facet in AppName.iml. Did you delete the tags from the correct .iml file?

Comment: Hmm, thanks for replying, wish I had this answer a couple days ago.  I *think* I tried deleting it from both, then only one and only the other, but not 100% sure.  In the end, I ended up having to recreate the project from scratch using the newest version of Studio, push my code and /res over to it, and it seemed to fix things.  Painful being on the bleeding edge sometimes.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Add an android facet to your module by following below steps.

1) Go To **File** Menu -> **Project Structure**, or press (**Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S**) shortcut to open "Project Structure".

2) Select "Facets" which is under the "Project Settings" tab. (First column)

3) Click on "+" button which is at the top of the Second Column to add new facets.

4) Select "Android" facet from that "Add "menu which will prompt another dialog box to select a module. (Select a module to which you want to apply this facet).

5) Select your module and that's it. :)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This helped me, Thank you very much. The gradle thing really sucks. Nothing but problems.

Comment: Eh, Gradle works when it works, lol. I wish it was back to ant.

Comment: @Gio I completely agree!!

Comment: ahm, I think the menu has changed in Android studio 0.5.8 , any idea where this setting is now?

Comment: when i press '+' button it says 'nothing here', what to do?

Comment: @jonney /Moin Please Update answer for latest versions

Comment: Ask the op to update. I did not post original answer

Comment: @SunilKumar I am facing the same issue as you. I also see nothing in the facet. I have also tried re installation of Android Studio: there are ? before the names of given SDK. I also have found a change:I have 32 bit Windows XP and Android API 25 platform is installed.

Comment: Please check for Android Support Plugin:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30574185/787399 I had a problem when it was disabled.

Comment: I followed your instructions but I don't see gradle in my imported project. Could someone point me what happened?

Answer (score 5):

At the toolbar left of the run and debug button there is a drop down. Select your project main activiy.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it helped to just go to "Edit Configurations..." and delete the current configuration. Then I just created a new one with the default options.