# Android Studio: Restart Error: No Android facet found for main

Tags: android, android-studio, facet

I have upgraded my Android studio to 2.9 and I have been getting this error when I try to run my code.

> Restart Error: No Android facet found for main

On surfing the web , I found this solution

[No Android facet found, issues compiling with Android Studio 0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625345/no-android-facet-found-issues-compiling-with-android-studio-0-2)

But the new Android studio does not have these options in the 'Project Structure'.
Can anybody suggest any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an update for AS 0.2.10. Try to update AS.

And if you still get the same error:

I don't know if this will help but you also could try to import your project instead of opening it (-> your `*.iml` files will be generated new by as). But be careful, you have to select the right file: `settings.gradle`.

Comment: Thank you I have updated Studio to 0.2.10 and tried, no luck. I created a new project and moved my old code, only then I could make it work.

Comment: I assume that importing the project by selecting the file 'settings.gradle' should also work.

Comment: On Importing the project using 'settings.gradle', I am getting 'Restart Error: Module is not found'

Comment: did you include the module in the `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: for reasons I am unaware of, everything is back to normal now :)

Comment: ok :) I just wanted to know if this would work! I also had a few times where AS is a little bit magic :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to open Project Structure of your project (right click on project -> Open Module Settings), and check if in Facets is added your project, if not - " + " add it. Its worked for me...