# no android facet found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to android, and I got an awkward error message. When I try to compile my project I get the error message "no android facet found", yesterday everything worked fine and I did not change a thing.

Can someone tell me why this error occurs out of nowhere? and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Android facet found, issues compiling with Android Studio 0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625345/no-android-facet-found-issues-compiling-with-android-studio-0-2)

Answer (score 1):

This problem happen to me after I changed the `src/build.gradle` and had to reimport the project into Android Studio.

After doing that I ended up with an two Run/Debug configuration one with the name of the original name my project: lets call it **helloWord** and another called **app**

The one with the original name  **helloWord** was having this problem, but the configuration called **app** worked fine (I was able to run it)

So I delete the setting with the facet problem **helloWord** and renamed the one called **app** back to the name of my project **helloWord**

Answer (score 1):

None of the answer worked for me. I got answer from some other site.

https://github.com/GcsSloop/AndroidNote/issues/8

File -> Settings - > Plugins -> Enable "Android Support" Plugin.

Everything works normal now.