# In android studio,cannot load 2 facets-unknown facet type:android and android-gradle

Tags: android-studio

When I open android studio I am getting an error- "Error loading project: Cannot load 2 facets. When I clicked to see the error the following appeared

> "2 facets cannot be loaded. You can mark them them as ignored to suppress this error notification.
>   **Unknown facet type:'android', Unknown facet type:'android-gradle'**

I tried to add facets ( In ***Project Structure*** > ***Project settings*** > ***Modules*** > clicked project name,  then clicked ***Android*** as well as ***Android-Gradle***) But both showed as "cannot load facet, unknown facet type." Under Project settings > Facets > both Android and Android-Gradle are displayed as 'Invalid facets'.
My project was running smoothly. This problem occured when I force-closed my laptop before exiting android studio as everything got stuck. After that whenever I open the android studio this problem occurs. I am not able to run my project. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Just enable `Android Support` plugin.

1. Click `Ctrl+Alt+S` in Windows or `Meta+Comma` in Mac.
2. In top search bar type "plugin".
3. On right side it will show a list of plugins, find `Android Support` plugin, check it and click `OK` at the bottom of screen.

This is how it looks:

[image: How to solve "cannot load 2 facets-unknown facet type:android and android gradle" problem]

Comment: I wonder why it was disabled in the first place. Never did it and suddenly I got those same errors.

Comment: Reenable red plugind in your plugin list

Comment: `Unable to apply changes: plugin "Google Cloud Testing" won't be able to load`. I got this error while enabling this.

Comment: disable that plugin @jankigadhiya in the same way we enabled Android Support

Comment: Strange I have mine already enabled. What I did on my end is to just uncheck and check it again. Then press ok. It seems to work now.

Comment: I tried doing exactly the same, but still unable to install that plugin. The error I am getting is `Unable to apply changes: plugin "Android Support" won't be able to load.` --- https://imgur.com/a/XsuFf

Comment: As suggested above by Zeus25, uncheck the Plugins that the error message complains about, and then re-check them, this should prompt Android into downloading the necessary dependencies for these plugins and ask you to restart the IDE.

Comment: This happened to me after Android Studio caused a windows bluescreen after trying to startup an emulator. The next time I opened android studio after the bluescreen it just showed a stack trace and asked me to report the error to some site. Then I opened it again and it was a blank slate with the android plugins disabled. Enabled the plugins and now everything is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 67):

In Android Studio go to

> File -> Settings - > Plugins -> Enable "Android Support" Plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

File, Then Settings->Plugin->Enable/Renable Plugin --> Apply --> Restart

Answer (score 2):

This problem occured when i'd updated Android Studio.

In case nothing from other answers works, you don't have another option, except removing broken settings and making clean setup.

So what i am suggesting:

- Use **Settings Repository** Feature to store personal IDE settings
- close studio
- remove **.AndroidStudioX** folder from user folder
- re-launch studio, do not copy settings from previous version (because settings probably broken and auto-import couldn't import it well)
- import personal settings from **Settings Repository**

Comment: Did this happen when you updated to Android Studio 3.1.0?

Comment: @fawaad Yes, it did

Comment: Do you know if there is an alternative method where you can keep your previous settings? I'm planning on looking this up later, just wondering if you know off hand.

Comment: As I mentioned in answer you can do it through settings repository or via export settings in options tab. Other settings not in the set won't be keeped

Answer (score 2):

For me I went to `Settings -> Plugins` and de-selected `Gradle` then immediately re-selected it. Android Studio then asked if I wanted to enable Groovy so I said yes and let it restart and now everything is happy again! (it was checked, but clearly somewhere deep down not truly enabled, so toggling the check-box sorted it)

Not sure if my cause was installing Flutter, but I did have to disable the Flutter plugin before I could build again.

Comment: I disabled and reenabled Android ADK to solve the problem. (Better than doing the same with Gradle, on which lots of other plugins depend.)

Comment: I believe it might have something to do with installing a cross-platform tooling. I suddenly ran into this problem after setting up React Native on my (Windows) machine. I had not touched Android Studio nor the SDK at all in the meantime, so it was pretty baffling how it sudenly got broken behind my back.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an ever-increasing number of facets - first 2, then 4, then 5 - and none of the above solutions worked. My solution (Android Studio 3.3, OS X) was to delete `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.3/disabled_plugins.txt`, which contained `org.jetbrains.android` and `org.jetbrains.maven`

I imagine if you have deliberately disabled plugins then you'll have to disable them again manually, but I was able to load all facets again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go To ->File->Settings->Plugins->disable/enable Android Support Plugins->Press Ok
   Just re-enable Android Support plugin. Then it will ask to restart.
   Restart them thats it

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in Android Studio 3.2.1 I had to re-import my project after that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem, I tried everything but nothing worked but then I remembered that I updated Android Studio just few hours back and then I enabled the plugins in the Android Studio and restarted it and it worked.

`File -> Settings -> Plugin` and then just press ok. It will ask to restart the android studio and please restart it.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to uncheck the plugin Android APK Support. I clicked Apply and then Ok to close the window. Android Studio prompted me to restart the program, and the program restarted. I checked the Android APK Support plugin again and restarted the program. And then I selected File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Then it worked just fine.