# Error Loading Project: Cannot load 3 facets Details

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and when I open Android Studio I am getting in my console an error- "Error loading project: Cannot load 3 facets Details..."

```
4:42:06 PM Error Loading Project: Cannot load 3 facets Details...
4:42:09 PM Plugins Suggestion
           Unknown features (Run Configuration[AndroidRunConfigurationType], Facet[android, android-gradle]) covered by disabled plugin detected.
           Enable plugins...
           Ignore Unknown Features
```

[image]

Does anyone have thoughts on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 111):

after opening android studio, open settings and the go to plugins,then do following steps

1. disable the firebase services
2. enable the android support plugin
3. restart android studio
4. go to settings and then to plugins
5. enable firebase services plugin
6. restart android studio

Comment: Thanks for this! Now the real question is how things got messed up in the first place.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter My situation definitely had something to do with a failed import of another android project. Probably clicked OK on some auto-detection prompt that messed with the plugins.

Comment: at least the errors are gone... thanks a lot... struggling with this issue for two days now... Now i hate the Android Studio most in the world

Comment: this is amazing. IDK how but it worked. Mind if you give a little detail about why firebase services were affecting the whole project build? I wasted my whole day on this.

Answer (score 98):

Solution:*error-loading-project-cannot-load-3-facets-details*.
While android studio is launched, go to File, Then Settings->Plugin->Enable Android Support Plugin

Comment: for me, I enable it through Android warning, it didn't work, so I disabled it again and re-enable it manually like the answer above.

Comment: Android Studio -> Preferences... -> Plugins -> "Android Support".
This works good for me, but I just want to point out the menu on "Plugins" is like the above on Android Studio 2.3.3.

Comment: I am getting error, when tried to do as suggested. The error is - `Unable to apply changes: plugin "Android Support" won't be able to load.` -- https://imgur.com/a/XsuFf

Comment: @NarendraJi I got this error as well. How did you fixed it?

Comment: How can I solve the error that @NarendraJi mentioned?

Comment: @JollyRoger--see my Answer further down the page. It could help, though it's now about six weeks since you last asked for help.

Answer (score 12):

After enabling the Android Support plugin (File->Settings->Plugins->Android Support), if you're using the Firebase Services plugin, you may need to disable Firebase Services, make sure Google Services is enabled, click 'Apply' and finally re-enable Firebase Services. 
This helped me when a an event log appears complaining of disabled plugin.

1. Click on Prompt to Enable plugin
   2.Uncheck Firebase service and automatically other plugins which had issues changed from red to White.
2. Click on OK.
3. A prompt pop up to restart Android studio appears
4. Huurray!

Answer (score 11):

*(Shorter solutions to the problem are shown above and have many thumbs up votes. If they don't work for you, several people have thanked me for this, so give it a try.)*

*I was using `Android Studio 3.0.1` and `Gradle 4.1` when I got the "Facets" errors. I fixed it by doing what follows.*

1. Stop AS. If AS is *hung*, force it to stop using Task Manager.
2. Restart AS. if you have errors and **NO WAY TO GET TO FILE>SETTINGS**…, you likely are where I was. Read on.
3. If you have a **popup about `facets`** that is similar to this...

[image]

4. ... look at **Gradle console**. If you get the message `Problems found loading plugins`, followed by a list of errors that say `“required plugin` **Android Support is disabled** " `, followed by a message that has a link saying " ...`( ***show balloon***)`, **click that link**.
5. The link will have an option to `Choose to` **enable Android Support** `. Do so.
6. Restart AS.
7. If you can get to `File > Settings` and have no errors, great. I guess you're finished.

But **I** faced a new error, so you may too:

8. If you get this error...

   ```
   Info:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, 
             :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,:app:mockableAndroidJar]
   Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

   Cause: **Write access is allowed from event dispatch thread only**
   ```
9. ... go to `File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location`.
10. Check the box `Use embedded JDK`.
11. Set `jdk location` to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`.

(*My* path was set to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`**1**`\jre`. The **1** is a little disconcerting, but ok so far.)

12. Hit `OK` and exit `Settings`.
13. Choose `Run` or `Debug` (or `Run …` or `Debug …`).

*(If you still have problems, check out the other Answers above and below.)* This is as good as I can do. Sorry if it didn't  help.

---

This seems to combine two or three threads about two or three problems:

```
Facet errors (I ignored the popup.)
Plugin errors (but no access to File Settings)
Write access only from dispatch thread (for which the fix seems unrelated).
```

Comment: how did you enable Run and Debug?

Comment: @Shruti--I couldn't enable "Run" or "Debug" because each was grayed out. But "Run ..." (i.e., you get to pick what to Run from a short list of your apps) and "Debug ..." (you get to pick what to Debug) were already enabled. I didn't do it. They just were enabled. But are you getting the popup about Facets? And the Balloon that you can show after Gradle Console errors? And does the balloon give option to Enable Android Support? And did you set JDK location as shown? If so, look for "Run ..." and click it. If you don't see it or it's grayed out, I don't know what to say.

Comment: Hey I got exact same popup about Facets and other issues after that, I followed your solution and now everything is working fine! :)

Answer (score 4):

For me I went to `Settings -> Plugins` and de-selected `Gradle` then immediately re-selected it, let Android restart and then disabled the Flutter plugin, let it restart again. See [this fuller answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49965307/865643) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Open android studio, open settings and then go to plugins, now disable all plugins and restart android studio. After restarting android studio open settings and then go to plugins, now enable all plugins then restart android studio. It should work after that.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings -> Plugins -> Android APK Support`. Make sure `Android APK Support` check field is checked. If not, check it and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message as you. After pondering and looking at the other answers, I found my solution.

On the Startup of Android Studio, I noticed that Windows Defender was producing notifications with the title Unauthorized Changes Blocked - Controlled Folder Access blocked...

Windows 10 has a feature called Controlled File Access, this supposedly prevents programs from modifying files on your `C:\ Drive`. 
By shutting this "Feature" off, Android Studio finally can work again!

Alternatively, you can leave this feature on and the whitelist certain Program Files (`.exe`), you'll need to allow `studio.exe`, `studio64.exe`, and some git executables as well. In theory, this should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Below Solution Might Help someone, it always work for me in Android Studio(Ubuntu)

Go to setting >> Plugins window

you will found too many plugins installed and enabled by default.

Check below listed 3 plugins

1) IntelliLang

2) JUnit

3) Kotlin

It might be already Enabled, if not then enable it.
if Enabled then Disable it and re-Enable.

Then Ok >> Apply and Restart Android Studio.

if not solve your problem disable all pugins and enable it again.
I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. All you need to do is to go to settings -> Plugins, then disable all the apps and restart your android studio. Then re-enable them again and restart. You should be fine after that exercise