# Android Studio 3.0.1 - Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I know this a duplicated question but i didn't find any answer validated for the problem .

I made the all the solutions in this question: [Android Studio 3.0 - Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986878/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-save-settings-failed-to-save-settings-please-re)
but what if my project wasn't a local project and is a remote project on Git .

every time i pull the master from git , this problem is showed up .

the problem was also in Version 3.0 even after updating the Studio
my version of Android Studio is 3.0.1

Comment: Why is this downvoted? "**i didn't find any answer validated for the problem .I [tried] the all the solutions"**. The guy's done all he can, did sufficient research, and, since there seems to be NO reliable solution to the problem (restart AS--does nothing), what else can he (and I) do but resubmit what he acknowledges is a "duplicated" question. Sometimes I wonder about the mentality of downvoters. I UPvoted it because it's my question, too--i.e., a GOOD question! (Oh--just noticed: someone's marked it as FAVORITE.)(Downvoter: explain yourself!)

Comment: @DSlomer64 thanks bro . i hope someone solves this problem

Comment: @amr-- I did solve it, but I am not using Git. I don't even know what Git is. Could you load the project without using Git and see what happens? It looks like maybe it's that "service" that lets several people work on same project. Yes? Just for the sake of just trying something, is there a way to convert to a regular project--like maybe export or something--and see if you get the error when loading it as normal? If you DO get the error, I can probably find where I solved it. It was NOT obvious and NOT easy. One led to another error several times. It seemed like LUCK that I fixed it.

Comment: @DSlomer64 ok tell me how you solved it as normal project not using git. i tried to make a project from beginning not using git but the same problem found.

Comment: --I don't know if this is an error I encountered and posted solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597007/error-loading-project-cannot-load-3-facets-details/48083794#48083794) Answer, but you might see if any of the error messages I got--and every error fixed led to another error--match your situation. I had two horrible problems about the same time and this was one solution. I'll look for the other, too.

Comment: [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597007/error-loading-project-cannot-load-3-facets-details/48083794#48083794) another possible source of help.

Comment: Finally (?),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040295/android-studio-unable-to-save-plugin-settings/48083927#48083927) may not be much different from a previoius one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't easy as the error doesn't look like others in the questions i mentioned above .

**First**

if your message error has word `plugins` in it you should see these answers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597007/error-loading-project-cannot-load-3-facets-details)
and these answers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040295/android-studio-unable-to-save-plugin-settings) helps too .

**In My Case**

the error is found if i tried to `Revert` Font File in the project we worked on as the message appears every time i launched Android Studio. I work remotely with others on `GIT`. So this is a a change in the master i pulled and every change i make in my branch wouldn't save.

I don't know if this rule is important if you work with git but i finally didn't make `Revert` to the file so the error message didn't show again and in the next launch of Android Studio the `Revert` message didn't show

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encounter the same issue, After updating the android studio I faced this issue and I tried all the possible solutions found on the internet.

My project has multiple modules and one of the modules is present inside a custom folder. (The same project has worked without any issue in the windows environment).

For example, In windows, the path for the module is "/internal/module name".
After importing the same project in mac the path should be changed to "./internal/module name".

After doing this the studio errors,
- Unable to save the setting
- Unable to find a matching configuration of the project.

All are resolved and I am able to build my project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `.idea` and restart Android Studio.