# Android Studio issues after update 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio used to function properly over the years until recently I updated it to version 3.0.1
Now I can't start new projects and when I open an old project this is what I get

[image]

**UPDATE**

After clicking 'Details' this is what I get (I was asked to censor the app's name by the client)

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's telling you what's wrong... get the plugin and click on "Details" to see what the problem is...

Comment: @DigitalNinja No, actually it doesn't, I tried several times before posting it to SOF

Comment: @DigitalNinja please check the updates question, that's what I get when I click details

Comment: I mean it looks like you don't have a plugin enabled that should be... I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560746/in-android-studio-cannot-load-2-facets-unknown-facet-typeandroid-and-android-gr

Comment: Much appreciated, that solved my problem!

Comment: Cool, you're welcome!