# "Help-->Find Action-->Randomly selected action" by mistake

Tags: android, android-studio, action, recover, file-recovery

My problem started when I was looking for the search function to find code in one of my Classes and dumb as I was I went to the tab many "Help-->Find action" and relized this was not the search function I was looking for.

Instead of just typing in "Ctrl + F" I pressed some random button in this "Find Action" function, pressed enter and Android Studio started doing something in the background. I first thought it was just Gradle which was syncing in the background but Android Studio restructured my whole project it seems and asked for a restart afterwards.

Now I can't run my Project or the "Application" tab that I normally have when I work on the left side is gone. How can I get my project back?

[This is my what my "Edit Run/Debug Configurations"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbeCs.jpg)

[Here is the project tab which I can't toggle to App any more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ky1N.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In android studio,cannot load 2 facets-unknown facet type:android and android-gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560746/in-android-studio-cannot-load-2-facets-unknown-facet-typeandroid-and-android-gr)

Answer (score 0):

Don’t worry, go to *file* menu and sync with grade files

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit slow and not very good at Android Studio, you mean "File"-->"Synchonize"? I've done that nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

Check the run configuration if it has selected the "app":

[image: run config]