# Android Support plugin doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I run my application, Android Studio notifies me with 3 errors as shown below

[image]

I have looked up the error on the internet and StackOverflow forums and I have found a solution to disable and re-enable `Android Support` plugin in settings but I didn't find the plugin and I didn't find a way to install it. Here is my plugin list:

[image]

As you see in the picture `Android Support` plugin doesn't exist.

Here is the reference what I have found on StackOverflow [In android studio,cannot load 2 facets-unknown facet type:android and android-gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560746/in-android-studio-cannot-load-2-facets-unknown-facet-typeandroid-and-android-gr)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the screen you have focus on **Android APK Support**.
Have you tried to disable and re-enable it? It seems that they have changed name from "Android Support" to "Android APK Support".

Comment: No I will try and update you with results

Comment: Thank you mate, you are right they seems to change to Android APK Support, when I disable and re-enable it and after restarting android studio, on application launch android studio will ask you to set the sdk location, I have reset it and it work

Comment: Try : **invalidate and restart **

Comment: I'm happy to hear it @AntoineElMurr ... Have a nice day