# Android Studio Unknown facet types

Tags: android-studio

Any android studio project I open gives me an error saying

`3 facets cannot be loaded
Java-Gradle (AppName). Unknown facet type: 'java-gradle'
Android-Gradle (app). Unknown facet type: 'android-gradle'
Android (app). Unknown facet type: 'android'`

I had accidently  set the files to open in notepad by default and I tried to fix it by deleting the file asscociation in the registry editor but it still doens't work but they no longer open in notepad by default.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560746/in-android-studio-cannot-load-2-facets-unknown-facet-typeandroid-and-android-gr) answer but there was no `Android Support` plugin

Comment: Then, it means that your Android Studio is corrupted.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: reinstall your Android studio.