# Including Android Support in Android Studio (2.3.3)

Tags: android, junit, plugins

I had Android Studio 2.3.3 for a while and never had to use it until now. So I installed some Android plugins on it, like JForm designer, WiFi ADB plugins and the rest to get started but it keeps telling me that Android Support (plugin) is not available. Please what can I do about it? Do I need to install any other plugins first, like JUnit? Or if I download the latest version of Android Studio, will it integrate Android support and tools for Android development?
I can send screenshots if they will be of relevance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this answer:
[In android studio,cannot load 2 facets-unknown facet type:android and android-gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560746/in-android-studio-cannot-load-2-facets-unknown-facet-typeandroid-and-android-gr)

If you couldn't find the `Android Support` plugin, checked for `Android APK Support.`