# No Android Facet Found in Module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just switched to Android-Studio from Eclipse. I am trying to run my application after setting up the gradle files. The project builds with no errors, however I can not run my app because there are no android facets found.

[image]

When I go to project structure there are no facets and I do not see any way to add a facet. How can I run my application?

[image]

Comment: perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625345/no-android-facet-found-issues-compiling-with-android-studio-0-2 ?

Comment: This does not work for me because there is no facets menu under project structure as that answer suggests @Bram

Comment: You don't have to manipulate facets manually in Android Studio, this bug notwithstanding. Perhaps click the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button after manually changing the build files?

Comment: It syncs and builds fine, but there are no facets. This project previously built in eclipse just fine.

Comment: Hey guys just found this on [SO][1] it worked for me!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625345/no-android-facet-found-issues-compiling-with-android-studio-0-2

Comment: I had seen that answer but my problem was that I could not add facets manually either

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved it by removing the .idea folder and any .iml files and then re-import the project into Android Studio.

If after importing you end up with the error **No facet found in module** you need to follow this steps

Go to `Run/Edit Configurations` and you will see at lest two configurations one with the name of the original name my project: lets call it **helloWord** and another called **app**

The one with the original name  **helloWord** was having this problem, but the configuration called **app** worked fine (I was able to run it)

So delete the setting with the facet problem **helloWord** and renamed the one called **app** back to the name of my project **helloWord**

Comment: Interesting, I will try this on another project and see if it works.

Comment: I got the problem again and solved it by: 1. submodule update 2. gradlew clean 3. rm -r .idea *.iml 4. re-import in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Th solution for me was to create a new project in android-studio. Then, copy over the code, resources, and dependencies to the new project. Then finally update the Gradle files manually and sync. Not perfect, but it worked and I can now upload to my device.

EDIT: This works but the method marked as the answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cache and restart worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I just solved my problem with the following steps, walk through with me:

> 1) **File** -> **Project Structure**, or press (**Ctrl**+**Alt**+**Shift**+**S**)
>   shortcut to open "Project Structure".
>
> 2) Select **Facets** which is under the **Project** **Settings** tab. (First
>   column)
>
> 3) Click on **+** button which is at the top of the Second Column to add
>   new facets.
>
> 4) Select **Android** facet from that **Add** menu which will prompt
>   another dialog box to select a module. (Select a module to which you
>   want to apply this facet).
>
> 5) Select your module and that's it.

Happy Coding!! ;)