# Nothing to Show in Android Project View

Tags: android-studio

When I open up the Android Project View n Android Studio, it says "Nothing to show". It seems that my projects modules are missing as well.

When I try to run the app I get error message:
Error running app: Module is not found

I also get the following error:
Unlinked Gradle project?
            Import Gradle project, this will also enable Gradle Tool Window.
            Don't want to see the message for the project again: press here.

When I try and import the gradle project, I get the following error
[image]

I don't have a clue as to how this happened. I'd be happy to provide more details, I'm not sure what other information is relevant.

[image]

Comment: Did you see your projects folder in your computer? Could you find your files there?

Comment: I see the projects folder, all of my files are present. I can actually open them in Android Studio

Comment: My .iml file is still there

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669652/no-android-facet-found-in-module) might help you.

Comment: Thanks but I should mention that this a project I have been working on for months in Android Studio. Everything was working fine until I did something to the project accidentally. I am not able to import the project from anywhere.

Comment: You can do several things: 1) delete the `gradlew` and gradle folder from the project or 2) download the latest gradle and run `gradle wrapper` in the project directory via command line. Make sure your `import` by click on on the build.gradle.

Comment: Could you post the project's Github repo if there is one? Would be nice to try ourselves to import into Android Studio for you, then we could offer a solution.

Answer (score 10):

I think your project was generated by eclipse. You try to import this older project as a android studio project.

You can follow below process:

Step 1. if you already open your android studio with another project just go to File -> Close Project
Step 2. If you already not open any project then skip step 1. Just Follow Image instruction.

[image: setp]

Step 3. Finally install your project SDK target plugin.

Answer (score 1):

"Nothing to Show" shows up in the Android project view if Android Studio can't detect a valid module in your app.  Due to the error you're seeing, Android Studio wasn't able to fully compile your app, meaning it can't build it's internal index of the project, so it isn't aware of your Android modules.

I recommend switching to **Project** view, which will show you all the files on disk (and do things like collapse packages for you), fixing the error (by updating the gradle wrapper version), and choosing to sync gradle with your project.  Once you have a compilable build, Android Studio will start showing the module in you **Android** view again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Restart did the work. so you can also give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Check all packages are installed or not. I wasted my two days in this. Go to sdk manager tab  and check these image for minimum required tools:

[image]

If they are not installed install them. Hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I (accidentally and no memories I guess...) moved my project root in a subfolder of my project directory. I just noticed I had my classic app, build and gradle folder + another folder in my project folder... in this child folder I had others app, build and gradle folders containing my real app files. I just removed anything in the parent folder and move the content of the child folder to it. It worked....

So my advice is, be sure that your app files are in the right folder and not in a subfolder, copy and paste can be evil sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened after I stopped the file `local.properties` to be tracked by Git. Somehow due to this reason, it deleted the file, causing nothing to show in Android Navigation Selection as shown in op's post. I restored `local.properties` file from Git, and brought back module structure.

**So please make sure that all relevant/important Android Studio and gradle files are present in the project, in order to display proper hierarchy.**

Answer (score 0):

**If nothing appears on the Gradle menu try to update or downgrading Your grade version that support to your android studio.**

You can see which gradle version is compatible for your project from this link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

First change class path on gradle pluging:
[image: Your Project name -> .Gradle]