# Android studio - No Android facet found for app

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi Everyone :) When I try to run the app, will pop up an error that

> "No Android facet found for app"

This situation began when I import a gson from `File > Project Structure > Dependency > '+'`. What does this message mean? How can I fix this problem?

Thanks all :)

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625345/no-android-facet-found-issues-compiling-with-android-studio-0-2

Comment: @TristanWiley But I can't see `Project Settings` tab in Project Structure. I only have `SDK Location` and `Project` tab.. See..(http://cowkite.dothome.co.kr/aaa.JPG)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops.. I solved it very easy. **Just delete `.idea` and any `.iml`, then re-import the project.** I don't know why have these symptoms occur. But if anyone have same problem, try this solution. Thanks. :)