# Can't run app projects on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Android Studio, and I installed it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64bit).

When I open the project in Android Studio, I get my project files marked with red and the debug configuration button beside the run button is marked with red X as shown in the below image:

[image]

Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: try rebuilding your project

Comment: i receive no android facet found??!!

Comment: It is not gradle project. follow theese steps:  https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625345/no-android-facet-found-issues-compiling-with-android-studio-0-2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of easy ways:

1. Close your currently opened project to go back to the welcome screen.
2. Choose **Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)** from the welcome screen.
3. Select an Eclipse ADT project to be imported.

[image: welcome screen of Android Studio]

Answer (score 3):

The best way to resolve this issue is as follows:

- Clean and then rebuild your project
- Make your project (it should work by now)
- Check your dependencies in gradle
- At the very end you can try invalidating the cache and restarting (Recommended)

The problem should be resolved by now.

Comment: this isn't useful unless how to do each step is explained, as OP says he's new to AS

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a difference between "`Open Folder`" and "`Open Project`".  If you "Open Folder" in a different project, I think it won't run that folder's project, but whatever project was opened last.

Answer (score -1):

when i try to run my project it give me the following error

> "ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve
>   com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.

Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: If you have problems, you should post them as a question, not as an answer, this isn't a forum...